# is it possible to prevent screenshot of view in ios?

Tags: ios, screenshot, screen-recording

I have some sensitive content in my app which I want to prevent from taking screenshot and screen recording. is it possible in iOS?

I have tried using screenshield Kit, but it only prevents UIlabels and Uiimageviews.

https://screenshieldkit.com

Comment: If out of the blue, you manage to prevent taking a screenshot, the user can capture the screen using another device.